# Delphi - How do I create a TJSONArray from a array of strings?

Tags: arrays, json, delphi

I have the following `array of strings`:

> 001,002,005,009

And I need to create a `TJSONArray` from it:

> ["001","002","005","009"]

```
 JSONObj := TJSONObject.Create;
 JSONObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Events', (response_faults as TJSONArray)));
```

I've tried to create the object and pass the array of strings **as** a `TJSONArray` but I'm getting:

> E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

How do I generate a `TJSONArray` from a `array of strings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct an empty `TJSONArray` object first, and then `Add()` the individual strings values to it.  For example:

```
var
  arr: array of string;
  JSONObj: TJSONObject;
  response_faults: TJSONArray;
  I: Integer;
begin
  arr := ... ; // '001', '002', '005', '009', ...
  JSONObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    response_faults := TJSONArray.Create;
    try
      for I := Low(arr) to High(arr) do begin
        response_faults.Add(arr[I]);
      end;
      JSONObj.AddPair('Events', response_faults);
    except
      response_faults.Free;
      raise;
    end;
    // use JSONObj as needed...
  finally
    JSONObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is throwing an `Access violation`.

Comment: Works fine for me as shown. Where exactly is the AV being raised? Is it during the `TJSONArray` preparation, or when you are using the `TJSONArray` afterwards? Please be more specific.

Comment: The AV was being raised at `response_faults.Add(arr[I]);`. I'm unit testing your code. Now it's working fine with the object Pair.

Comment: There is no way that line can raise an AV if `response_faults` is a valid object, and `arr[I]` is a valid array index. And `TJSONArray` does not require `TJSONObject` to operate. So something else has to be causing your AV.